# How would I get the largest portion of valid HTML code given invalid input in Python?

Tags: python, html

I would like to make some sort of HTML parser which takes in some code that is invalid: i.e. has a start tag without an end tag or vice versa, and return the largest portion of valid HTML.

Example Input:

```
         <h1>asdf</h1>
             <p>p1</p>
             <p>p2</p>
         <h2>asdf2</h2>
             <p>p1</p>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Output:

```
         <h1>asdf</h1>
             <p>p1</p>
             <p>p2</p>
         <h2>asdf2</h2>
             <p>p1</p>
```

I considered using some sort of stack-like representation combined with Python's HTMLParser but I'm not sure how I would implement it. I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Something with a tag stack and a content stack:

- opening tag: push tag on tag stack
- content : push on content stack
- closing tag: pop and output opening tag, pop and output content, output closing tag

Comment: yeah that's along the lines of what I was thinking but the nested structure makes actually printing it difficult. It would work for this example but if you had a <body> tag before the segment, you couldn't print out the body tag very easily

Comment: I think you need to specify the problem better then, you didn't say you wanted to output unmatched opening tags. I assumed if you don't want unmatched closing you also do not want unmatched opening. As it is, the problem is incompletely specified.

Comment: no you were correct in your initial assumption. in the example above if you had a body tag before everything in the input, it would be matched to the </body> tag